# php - base64 encoded data is lost after json_encode

Tags: php, json, base64, php-openssl

I use the following code to generate a encrypted string for a given string.

```
class MY_class{
    public static function cryption($string){
        $output = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($string, $cipher_method, $key, 0, $iv));
        $output = $iv . $output;
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Using this code I generated the encrypted id of the id of a model object and replaced the original id.

```
$Model_object = Model_class::find(1);
$Model_object->id = MY_class::cryption($Model_object->id);
echo json_encode($Model_object);
```

For a given instance `print_r()` of `$Model_object` after replacing the original id with encrypted id gives me the following result.

```
[index] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4df73f34cUYxVmVLWlFUU2M9
    )
```

But `json_encode()` only outputs only the first decimal digits of the of the encrypted id.

```
{"id":4}
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can explain why this is happening and how to overcome this problem.

P.S. I have already googled this problem and searched in Stack Overflow too. So, don't mention it in comments.

Comment: Did you try enclosing it in double quotes?

Comment: You've pared out so much code from your question that there's no way to actually tell what's going on. Please update your question with *valid* code that demonstrates the problem. Even better if that code is a *runnable* example.

Comment: Chances are that you are assigning the id to an *integer* variable implicitly. And the type conversion transforms "4d..." in 4. It is not taking the first digit, it is taking the *only* decimal digits. Try setting the id to 1337abc or abc1337 and see what happens.

Comment: @andrewnagyeb I tried setting the type of encrypted id to string using `settype()`. I think that should do the enclosing it in double quotes. But it didn't work either.

Comment: @LSerni Yeah, that's what happening. I didn't had words to explain that at the time of writing the question. I'll update the question. Do you know a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Sammitch This is an ongoing business project. So I have to make sure the security of the code base. But, I'll try to supply a _runnable_ code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LSerni said, I was implicitly assigning the encrypted id which is a *string* to the *integer* property `$Model_object->id`.

So I created a new dynamic property `$Model_object->encrypted_id` and assigned the encrypted id to it and called that property on the other side. It worked like a charm.

Thank you very much @LSerni for your insight on the problem.